# Interpretation of Fermi-Dirac statistics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, fermions

I was reading that as temperature increases the energy at which $n(E)=0.5$ shifts to lower energies as these lower energy states become depopulated. Could someone explain that, what it means and why is that so?

In addition, what is the proper interpretation of saying $n(E_{F})=\frac{1}{2}$, where $E_{F}$ is the Fermi energy?

Also, why is it the the Fermi energy is raised in a n type semiconductor and lower in a p type semiconductor?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean a little more by your first statement? I'm not sure it's entirely correct...

Comment: Got that statement from Townsend's quantum physics.

Comment: What exactly was said and in what context? Or a page reference and I will try and find it

Comment: page 232 first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

So the fermi-dirac distribution function has the form $$n\left(E\right)=\frac{1}{\exp \left(\frac{E-E_F}{k_bT}\right)+1}$$
So for $E=E_F$ you can see that $n\left(E_F\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ regardless of the value of $T$ so I am not entirely sure what you mean by the first statement in your question.

If you plot the FD distribution function at different energies you will see that the graph "softens" [image]. (Image taken from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics)

If you consider the function at zero temperature you have no states filled above the Fermi level and every state filled below the Fermi level. As you increase the temperature occupied states which are within $\approx k_bT$ of the Fermi level can be thermally excited to empty states above the Fermi level. So you can think of it as states from energies roughly $E_F-k_bT\rightarrow E_F+k_bT$ which are changing their occupation. So you could imagine that the states at the two extremes are changing their occupation very rarely i.e. the one at $E_F+k_bT$ is empty most of the time and the one $E_F-k_bT$ is mostly filled.

For the states in around the Fermi energy, they change their occupation quite regularly due to thermal excitations. The state at exactly $E_F$ is filled half the time from the form of the distribution function.

As for the semiconductors, I'm no expert on condensed matter theory but I think you could probably think of it this way. The n-type semiconductor has dopants which produce more electrons to conduct. So if you think of the material originally having $N$ electrons now we have some $N+n$ electrons to conduct, which now have to fill up more states in the material pushing the Fermi level higher.

A p-type semiconductor has dopants which remove the number of mobile electrons which can conduct current, so the converse argument applies we now have $N-n$ electrons conducting.

(I wouldn't quote me on the last bit)

---

I have actually been a little lax and used a low temperature version of the FD distribution function I should be using something like 
$$n\left(E\right)=\frac{1}{\exp \left(\frac{E-\mu}{k_bT}\right)+1}$$
where $\mu$ is the electrochemical potential and is related to the Fermi energy by $$\mu=E_F\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\pi k_bT}{2E_F}\right)^2\right)$$
so that might relate to your first point.
I'm just used to dealing with systems were $E_F>>k_bT$ so I didn't make the distinction.

Comment: How would you explain n(E)=0.5 to someone? what are the implications? I like the explanation for the last part though, thank you.

Comment: That if you were to measure the occupation of that state at energy $E$ half the time it is occupied with an electron and half the time it isn't due to thermal fluctuations. I'm not sure there is much more that you can say it about it other than that.

Comment: @alejandro123 have a look at my edit, it answers your first point.

Comment: Normally $E_F$ is a few $eV$ in metals. The thermal energy at room temperature is about two orders of magnitude less so that second term is negligible and $E_F\approx \mu$

Comment: @alejandro123: you're on the threshold between the occupied states $n=1$ and the unoccupied ones $n=0$; of course you get $n=0.5$ somewhere in between where the electrons are hopping between states of the same energy but there's not enough electrons to fill all the states...